# Django: how to set log level to INFO or DEBUG

Tags: python, django, logging, configuration-files

I tried to change the debug level to DEBUG in Django because I want to add some debug messages to my code. It seems to have no effect.

My logging configuration:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console':{
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request':{
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

Code:

```
import logging ; logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug("THIS MESSAGE IS NOT SHOWN IN THE LOGS")
logger.warn("THIS ONE IS")
```

Output on the console:

```
WARNING:core.handlers:THIS ONE IS
```

I also have tried setting DEBUG = False and DEBUG = True in my settings file. Any ideas?

**Edit:** If I set the log level on the logger directly, it works:

```
import logging ; logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.debug("THIS MESSAGE IS NOT SHOWN IN THE LOGS")
```

Output:

```
DEBUG:core.handlers:THIS MESSAGE IS NOT SHOWN IN THE LOGS
WARNING:core.handlers:THIS ONE IS
```

But: It seems the config file is totally ignored. It prints both statements **always** even if I set both entries in the config back to ERROR. Is this the correct behaviour or am I still missing something?

Comment: Quick check: `logger.warn("Log level is set to {0}".format(logging.getLevelName(logger.level)))`

Comment: WARNING:core.handlers:Log level is set to NOTSET.

So it is the default level which is WARNING, right?

Why doesn't Django change it accordingly to my settings?

Comment: *blink* Huh. I got nothing. It looks to me like you're doing everything right.

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to add e.g.

```
'core.handlers': {
    'level': 'DEBUG',
    'handlers': ['console']
}
```

in parallel with the `django.request` entry, or

```
'root': {
    'level': 'DEBUG',
    'handlers': ['console']
}
```

in parallel with the 'loggers' entry. This will ensure that the level is set on the logger you are actually using, rather than just the `django.request` logger.

**Update:** To show messages for all your modules, just add entries alongside `django.request` to include your top level modules, e.g. `api`, `handlers`, `core` or whatever. Since you haven't said exactly what your package/module hierarchy is, I can't be more specific.

Comment: That works. But is there a way to show only MY debug logs? If I set the 'root' entry I get all the sql queries in the logging which I am not interested in. Setting the core.handlers restricts the debug output to core.handlers. But I'd like to see all debug output in my files (all handlers.py, api.py and what else I have).

Comment: @kev did you found the solution? :)

Comment: Sort of. I have created a custom file logger like here: http://pastebin.com/srT4mSdu, import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('custom')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

Answer (score 6):

I fixed it by changing

```
LOGGING = {
    ...
}
```

to:

```
logging.config.dictConfig({
    ...
})
```

For example to log all messages to the console:

```
import logging.config
LOGGING_CONFIG = None
logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'console': {
            # exact format is not important, this is the minimum information
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'console',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
    # root logger
        '': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
    },
})
```

Comment: The question was about Django, you are just bypassing the whole Django logging system here...

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this is a minimum configuration with settings.py to change log level with root logger.

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    "root": {
        "level": "INFO"
    }
}
```