# Set the logging level on the root logger in Django tests

Tags: django, logging, nosetests

I have the following config (based on [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#examples)):

```
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
},
```

When I run my tests like this (Django 1.8.4)

```
./manage.py test
```

I get DEBUG-level output from a source line in my own code that looks like

```
import logging
logging.debug("Shouldn't be seen, but is")
```

The line indicates the log message is going to the root logger, as I would expect:

```
DEBUG:root:blah: Shouldn't be seen, but is
```

As the tests are running it says

```
nosetests --verbosity=1
```

If I say

```
./manage.py test --verbosity=0
```

that nosetests message goes away, but the debug logging does not.

What is happening?  Is my logging config wrong?  Is nosetests interfering?  Django?

I think my logging config is being read.  I suppressed a django.request WARNING by configuring that logger in this config file.

How do I debug this?

(I read [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720785/django-how-to-set-log-level-to-info-or-debug), it didn't help.)

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you come up with a solution since?

Comment: Sadly, I don't remember.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logger configuration is not written correctly. The 'root' configuration goes outside the 'loggers' part, like this:

```
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
},
'root': {
    'handlers': ['console'],
    'level': 'INFO',
}
```

Setting it up as this should work.